# Changing the coulmn values in the dataframe given the condition in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a code optimization problem at hand, currently in python using pandas.
(similar to one at hand, cannot use the exact problem statement at hand)

Suppose I have measurement points for certain set of `langitude` and `latitude`. These are currently attached to country level information. i.e. n pair(s) of Lat. and Long. have also a column of Capital Longitude and Capital Longitude (Lat and Long of the capital city.) . Thus the dataset has columns:
`meas_lat, meas_long, capital_lat, capital_long`

There is another dataframe which has information on how to divide the country into more smaller chunks, lets say *states/provinces*. The columns are, 
`capital_lat, capital_long, state_capital_lat, state_capital_long, state_width, state_length` considering that states are all of square/rectangle shape.

Now the measurements have to be mapped to state-level. We are currently using Pandas.

```
# loop over all the rows having the state layout info
for row in state_layout:
    # for a given state layout,
    # check which measurement points lie within the state boundaries
    # for the valid measurement points, change the capital location to state capital location.
    for meas_row in meas_data:
        mask = ((meas_data.meas_lat <= row.state_x_max) & (meas_data.meas_lat >= row.state_x_min) & 
                (meas_data.meas_long <= row.state_y_max) & (meas_data.meas_long >= row.state_y_min))
        meas_data.loc[mask, ['capital_x','capital_y']] = row.state_capital_x, row.state_capital_y
```

What are the suggested ways to improve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Look into geopandas (pandas specifically for geographic data), something similar to this might work:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/geopandas-find-nearest-point-in-other-dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned that this example is an equivalent of the actual problem, which is not GIS based.